# Finding a weak open neighbourhood of a Hilbert space with a certain property

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

Let $X$ a Hilbert space. I will write BWON for a basic weak open neighbourhood of $0$ in $X$.

Let $U$ a BWON, and for each $1\leq i \leq n$, let $f_i: X \to X$ be a weakly continuous map. I want to show that there exists some other basic weak open neighbourhood $V$ with the property that for each $1\leq i \leq n$

\begin{equation}
2V + 2f_i(V) \subseteq U.
\end{equation}

I am not yet fully comfortable with the notion of weak topology, so I would appreciate if you could let me know if the following attempt at a proof works.

Suppose $V_1, \dots ,V_n$ are BWONs with the property that for each $1\leq i \leq n$
\begin{equation}
2V_i + 2f_i(V_i) \subseteq U.
\end{equation}
Then we may find some BWON $V$ such that
\begin{equation}
V \subseteq \bigcap_{1\leq i\leq n} V_i.
\end{equation}
Then $V$ has the required property that for each $1\leq i \leq n$
\begin{equation}
2V + 2f_i(V) \subseteq U.
\end{equation}
So if we can show that we can find a $V_1$ such that $2V_1 + 2f_1(V_1) \subseteq U$, we are done.

Since $f_1$ is weakly continuous, then so is $g_1 = 2I + 2f_1$. Then since $U$ is open, then $g_1^{-1}(U)$ is a weakly open set containing $0$. Therefore we may find a BWON $V_1$ contained in $g_1^{-1}(U)$, and so

\begin{equation}
2V_1 + 2f_1V_1 = g(V_1) \subseteq g(g_1^{-1}(U))\subseteq U,
\end{equation}
as required.

I would appreciate if you let me know if this works, and even corrections of small mistakes are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you argument is correct. The only thing I would mention is that $ \bigcap_{1\leq i\leq n} V_i$ is open because it is a *finite* intersection of open sets.